# bxSlider within show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

My page's content is toggled using different links, showing one `div` at a time using a jQuery 'showonlyone' function. On loading the page, none of the divs should be displayed. I got it working fine, until i tried to put a picture slider (bxSlider) within one of the divs,  `newboxes1`.

Outside the box, the bxSlider works fine. Within it, the pictures don't show. See live example [here](http://megalife.fr/test/test.html).

Here's what my code looks like :

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }
     });
}</script>  
</script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

$(function(){
  var slider = $('#slidersample').bxSlider({
    mode:'fade',
    controls: false
  });
  $('#bx-prev-sample').click(function(){
    slider.goToPreviousSlide();
    return false;
  });
    $('#hover-next-g-sample').click(function(){
    slider.goToPreviousSlide();
    return false;
  });
  $('#bx-next-sample').click(function(){
    slider.goToNextSlide();
    return false;
  });
  $('#hover-next-d-sample').click(function(){
  slider.goToNextSlide();
  return false;
  });
});
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="left-menu">
<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >LINK 1</a><br />
<a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >LINK 2</a><br />
<a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >LINK 3</a>
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1">DIV 1
<!-- SLIDER -->
<div id="slider" style="margin-top: 0px; width="580 px"; height="375 px">
<div class="bx-prev"><div id="bx-prev-sample">←</div></div>
<div class="bx-next"><div id="bx-next-sample">→</div></div>
<div class= "hover-next-g"><div id="hover-next-g-sample" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div></div>
<div class= "hover-next-d"><div id="hover-next-d-sample" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div></div>
<ul id="slidersample" width="580px" height="375 px" style="margin:0px ; padding:0px">
  <li><img src="images/1.jpg" width="580" height="375" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/2.jpg" width="580" height="375" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/3.jpg" width="580" height="375" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- SLIDER END-->
</div>

 <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">DIV 2<br /></div>

 <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">DIV 3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use

```
.newboxes {display:none;}
```

in the CSS so none of the divs are showing when the page is loading. Removing this from the CSS solves the bxSlider issue, as you can see [here](http://megalife.fr/test2/test2.html). However, the content is shown when the page is loaded, while I want all of it to be hidden. Any attempt to use `display:block` or `display:none` elsewhere in the code has been unsuccessful.

Can anyone think of a way to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

I had the similar problem with bxSlider plugin: when the DIV that contained it was initially hidden `display:none`, the slideshow would not appear when I make the DIV visible `$('#div-id').show();`. Only slideshow control buttons appeared. Then I solved the problem like this:

```
<script>

var mySlider;

$(function() {

    mySlider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
            easing: 'easeInCubic',
            displaySlideQty: 3,
            moveSlideQty: 1,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            hideControlOnEnd: true
    });

    $("#processSignUp").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
        $("#trainings-slide").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
        mySlider.reloadSlider();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
    });

});

</script>
```

As you can see I reloaded the slideshow **just after** the DIV (that contain the slider) was showed and it worked perfectly. Maybe that can help to solve your problems and to avoid using visibility:hidden and other tricks.

Comment: Great answer - note that latest BX slider version the function is reloadSlider() not reloadShow()

Comment: If if I don't have a pointer to mySlider anymore? or if I want to reload all slides with some css class? $('.bxslider').reloadSlider() doesn't work

Comment: not working for me: Uncaught TypeError: slider.reloadSlider is not a function

Answer (score 6):

I know this question was asked awhile ago but I have the same issue. I have no idea whats up with bxSlider and display:none. It doesn't seem to read the content if its contained in a div with the display set to none.

I've gotten around it thus far by toggling `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` instead of display.

Answer (score 2):

You can use visibility:hidden and visibility:visible, but will some troubles. And you can use height:0px;overflow:hidden;
I`m use last solve

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to allow bxslider to load, then hide it once it has.

```
<script>
    var mySlider;

    $(function() {
        mySlider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
            easing: 'easeInCubic',
            displaySlideQty: 3,
            moveSlideQty: 1,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            hideControlOnEnd: true,
            onSliderLoad: function() {
                $('#trainings-slide').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this isn't working for me, results in exactly the same thing happening.