# Bxslider, partial postback and slideToggle resetting the slider width

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms, slidetoggle, bxslider

My bxslider works, however when I try to run it after in a) an updatepanel or b) a jquery ajax call, the width resets to 100px rather than the width of my outer div which is 960px. This happens after some basic animation e.g slideToggle or show. Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            var eventSlider = $("#season-slider").bxSlider();

        $(".event-list li a").click(function() {
            //var eventID = $(this).
            var selectedIndex = $(this).closest("li").index();

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow',
            function() {
                eventSlider.goToSlide(selectedIndex - 1);
            });

            //eventSlider.reloadShow();
        });

        $(".down-slide-panel").stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow', "easeOutQuart", function () {});
        }
        else {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Its widths have been reset to 100px when I do the slideToggle bit, if I don't slideToggle it works fine. So I tried changing the slidetoggle to show() and had the same issue. Why are these animations resetting its width to 100px?

The odd thing is this only happens in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, not in IE7 or IE8!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here, though a slightly different problem as they were using .show(), but same solution for slideToggle()

[bxSlider within show/hide divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071269/bxslider-within-show-hide-divs)

Simple doing the below after the slideToggle() made it work across all browsers.

```
eventSlider.reloadShow();
```