# How to create a string and use a function that's named after it?

Tags: javascript, string, function, bxslider

Sorry for bad wording in the question but it's hard to explain for me. I'm using several bxsliders on a page and some are placed in hidden divs. Unfortunately images are not shown in the slider after making the parent div visible unless the slider is reloaded (See here: [bxSlider within show/hide divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071269/bxslider-within-show-hide-divs)). So let's say I initiate the sliders at the beginning with:

```
var slider_0=$("#slider_0 .bxslider").bxSlider({
    //bxslider options here
});

var slider_4=$("#slider_4 .bxslider").bxSlider({
    //bxslider options here
});

var slider_7=$("#slider_7 .bxslider").bxSlider({
    //bxslider options here
});
```

The sliders are not consecutively numbered but there is a navigation and if I click the 7th element it leads to slider_7. So I could get the index of the clicked item with:

```
$(this).index();
```

When I call `slider_7.reloadSlider();` it would work but I don't know which slider the user clicks and which number it has. So would it be possible to call that with a created string like this:

```
slider_name='slider_'+$(this).index();
slider_name.reloadSlider();
```

works not of course. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It sounds like your slider html looks like this: `<div id="slider_0" class="bxslider"></div>`, then your init should be `var slider_4=$("#slider_0").bxSlider({});` and you can target them with `$("#slider_" + $(this).index()).reloadSlider();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution:

```
eval("slider_" + $(this).index()).reloadSlider();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a dictionary with strings as keys and functions as values. Then, you could have O(1) lookup of the functions you're targeting.

In general, you can do it like so:

```
// set up your dictionary
var dictionary = {};

// add your functions
dictionary['methodName'] = function() {};

// call the functions
dictionary['methodName']();
```

So, for your example, you could do:

```
dictionary['slider_7'] = slider_7.reloadSlider;

dictionary['slider_'+$(this).index()]();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it doesnt seem to work for me because I set up the sliders in php before. So my code is: ... $sliders['slider_'.$u]='slider_'.$u.'.reloadSlider()'; } } //it's a loop ?> and then var dictionary=<?php echo json_encode($sliders); But if I do that following error occurs: TypeError: dictionary[("slider_" + $(...).index(...))] is not a function, probably because it's passed as string and not as object

Comment: eval("slider_" + $(this).index()).reloadSlider(); was working for me

Comment: @user2718671 if you need a php solution, then your question should reflect that.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I just didn't want to overcomplicate it because I thought there would be a simple javascript solution and I'm glad that with eval() there was one ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger it with

```
window["slider_" + $(this).index()].reloadSlider()
```

Although, I'm not sure whether your approach is the best. I think I'd go with arrays or with object (as a key-value pairs)

Comment: Thx. That was close but you can't use an object property this way. It's the wrong syntax. But console.log(window["slider_" + $(this).index()]) selects the right object. I found the following solution: eval("slider_" + $(this).index()).reloadSlider();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
slider_name='slider_'+$(this).index();
$("#" + slider_name + " .bx_slider").reloadSlider();
```

Comment: Thx. That's what I tried at first but it didn't work. That's the reason I posted this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear here what you want/are trying to do. What it seems like you want to do is get a programmatic handle on a specific slider when a user clicks a specific part of your page. You do not accomplish this by `eval()`ing a string...that's what event handlers are for. So create a click event handler and in that event handler

```
$('#idOfWhatTheUserClicksOn').click(function(event) {
    var slider = document.getElementById('#idOfRelatedSlider');
    $(slider).bxSlider();
    //if you need the current value of the slider you can get that too
    var value = slider.value;
});
```

You could achieve the same with fewer LOC by using a class instead of id's with different handlers, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thx. But I don't get it how to connect these code snippets with my example. Btw it's not the slider I'm clicking on, it's a navigation that shows the div with the slider so I guess that won't work anyway. Still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var slider_cache = [
    $("#slider_0 .bxslider").bxSlider(),
    $("#slider_1 .bxslider").bxSlider(),
    $("#slider_2 .bxslider").bxSlider()
];
```

...

```
slider_cache[$(this).index()].reloadSlider();
```